# ubuntu nginx on local machine. Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I installed `nginx, php (php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-fpm php-pear php5-cgi php5-odbc php5-curl)`, odbc on my local PC with Ubuntu. And it worked correct until (I guess) I restarted the system. Now I'm getting

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

My config:

```
odbc.ini
[My_DB]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = My_DB
Trace = No
Server = x.x.x.x
Port = 5000
TDS Version = 5.0
Database = dbname
        
odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver v0.63 with protocol v8.0
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount = 2
        
freetds.conf
[My_DB]
host = x.x.x.x
port = 5000
tds version = 5.0
```

What I found about ODBC in `phpinfo()`:

> PDO drivers   mysql, odbc
>
> ODBC driver for PDO   Wez Furlong
>
> ODBC  Stig Bakken, Andreas Karajannis, Frank M. Kromann, Daniel R. Kalowsky

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what does your phpinfo() say, is the odbc extension included?

Comment: @Florian please, look my updated answe

Comment: hmm, sorry, then i have no idea :/ Maybe someone other can help you.

Comment: Are you calling the function from inside a namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the (standalone) [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php) package installed, but rather the [PDO drivers for ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).
You could use them with PDO like

```
$connection = new PDO('odbc:MSSQLServer', $username, $password);
```

But to use the `odbc_*` functions, it appears you need to enable at least one package listed on the [installation page](http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.installation.php) when compiling PHP.
On Ubuntu, you might want `--with-unixODBC`, but what you actually need depends on how you use those functions.

But if you're using PHP from `apt-get`, you might wanna try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-odbc
```

Comment: As I noticed at my question `php-odbc` is already installed. Regarding to your advice `--with-unixODBC`, does it mean that I should reinstall php compiling it manually?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Did you run `php5enmod odbc` as well?